# Which one is better to define Enum by static Object or const string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm working a React-Native project. Within the project, I need to define 200-300 enum. I want to use Enum like in Java, and also I can use Enum as a key in immutable.js Map/Set. That makes my code pretty easy to write. However, I can replace these Enum object by string. Now my concern is memory usage. I don't know if an object will consume a lot of memory or not. Which one is better? Any advises?

```
export class Enum {
  static values() {
    return Object.values(this).filter(value => value instanceof Enum);
  }

  static build() {
    let count = 0;
    for (const [key, value]: [string, any] of Object.entries(this)) {
      if (value instanceof Enum) {
        value._ordinal = count++;
        value._name = key;
        makeImmutable(value);
      }
    }
    Object.freeze(this);
  }

  _ordinal: number;
  _name: string;

  name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  ordinal() {
    return this._ordinal;
  }

  toString() {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
  }
}

export class ReduxAction extends Enum {
  static LOGIN = new ReduxAction();
  static LOGOUT = new ReduxAction();
}
ReduxAction.build();

export function login() {
  return {type: ReduxAction.LOGIN};
}

export class Game extends Enum {
  static GAME_A = new Game('A', (data) => data.length);
  static GAME_B = new Game('B', (data) => data.length * 2);

  name: string;
  countScore: Function;
  constructor(name: string, countScore: Function) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.countScore = countScore;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered [`Symbol()`](http://2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html) instead?

Comment: You may also want to consider [`WeakSet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain enough. I've modified my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 developer here. Objects are, of course, bigger than strings (especially since in your case, you have the string anyway, and the question is whether you have an object in addition to that). For the code in your snippet, every instance of `Enum` should be 5 pointers large (3 pointers for the object header, 2 for the `_ordinal` and `_name` properties; so object size will be 5 * 8b = 40 bytes on 64-bit platforms). There's also some memory cost for every "object shape" in the program, which in this case translates to "every class you define".

I would *guess* that the memory cost is acceptable, given the requirements/goals you have stated. Depending on how you'd structure your code, there's also a chance that in order to switch to strings here, you'd have to use more memory elsewhere to maintain the same functionality or interface.

As a side note: all the reflection functionality tends to be somewhat slow. For example, keeping the "values" list as an array and handing it out when requested would be much faster than the `Object.values(this).filter(...instanceof...)` chain. However, given that you say you're optimizing for easy coding, that may be another cost that's acceptable in order to achieve the tradeoffs you desire.

Comment: I don't think he's concerned about creating 200 objects or 200 strings. The difference should be in how often they are used (e.g. in the `login` function), and my understanding is that both come down to pointers of the same size - it doesn't matter whether an object or a string lies behind them.

Comment: Agreed; if you just look at a snippet like `{type: ReduxAction.LOGIN}`, then it doesn't make a difference whether `ReduxAction.LOGIN` points to an object, or a string, or a number, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you all! In fact, I only have 10 to 20 ReduxActions, so I don't really worry that. But, I have about 500 static Game objects (I counted yesterday) which is what I really worry about. As @jmrk mentioned, even if I don't use Enum, I still have to maintain the same data somewhere else. The Game Enum is just a wrapper to wrap all data together. And for "values()", I don't use often in the code, so it's ok to remain there.

Comment: @Bergi, most of them are not often to use, but with them defined as Enum, I can write this kinda code to avoid switch pattern.
    render() { return Map([ [Game.GAME_A, () => <GameA />], [Game.GAME_B, () => <GameB />] ]).get(game)() }

Comment: @jmrk, one more question please, is case 1 better than case 2? What is the memory cast for them? Case 1: render() { return Map([ [Game.GAME_A, () => List([1, 2, 3] )], [Game.GAME_B, () => List([4, 5, 6])] ]).get(game)() }, Case 2: ender() { return Map([ [Game.GAME_A, List([1, 2, 3]) ], [Game.GAME_B, List([4, 5, 6]) ] ]).get(game) }

Comment: Case 1 has needless overhead (each function object needs memory, each call needs time). In general, a simple `x` is (obviously?) more efficient than `(function() { return x; })();`.